# Why doesn't my function execute when I use exec on a string? (the string is the name of the function)

Tags: python, function, exec, execute

I have the following function in python:

```
def foo():
    print 1 
    return 1
```

In the shell, I run

```
foo()
```

and I get

```
1
1
```

as I should.  But when I run the following in the shell

```
exec('foo')
```

I get nothing?  why?

This is a diluted version of a much larger problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only *referencing* the function name. Add parenthesis to actually *call* the function:

```
exec('foo()')
```

This will print `1`; the return value is discarded as nothing captures it. You could add an extra print statement to show the return value:

```
exec('print foo()')
```

`exec()` does not mean 'execute the function named', it means 'execute the python code given'.